# How to add text to asp:BoundField in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, oledb

I have the following GridView in which data is being fed from the `OleDB` Database.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSavingsTracker" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        ...
        <asp:BoundField DataField="interestRate" HeaderText="Interest Rate" />
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And I am reading the contents from the Database and printing in the GridView in the following manner:

```
protected void ShowGridView()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnString();
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    string sqlQuery = "select * from ... ";
    OleDbCommand showGridViewCommand = new OleDbCommand(showGridViewQuery, con);
    showGridViewCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter olda = new OleDbDataAdapter(showGridViewCommand);
    olda.Fill(dt);

    GridViewSavingsTracker.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewSavingsTracker.DataBind();

    con.Close();

}
```

**What I want to do:** I want to append `%` symbol to the contents of interestRate column in the GridView such that they should be displayed as `3%` instead of `3`. But the % symbol should not be inserted into the Database. In other words, the `%` symbol should only be used for display purposes in the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you store the interest rate in the database will depend on which one of the below solutions remedy your question,

If the interest rates are formatted such that 0 = 0% and 1 = 100% you can use:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="interestRate" HeaderText="Interest Rate" DataFormatString="{0:p}"/>
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Otherwise you will need to do a template

```
<columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Interest Rate:">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="IntRate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InterestRate") + "%" %>'></asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
```

Updating answer as per comments below

```
protected void GridViewSavingsTracker_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    var row = GridViewSavingsTracker.Rows[index];
    var interestRate = ((Literal row.FindControl("IntRate")).Text;
    if (e.CommandName == "SomeCommand")
    {
        TextBoxInterestRate.Text = interestRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am trying the 2nd option that you gave me. I will give you feedback once I complete it. I am storing the Interest Rates in the Database as they are. I mean, if the Interest Rate is 6, then it means 6%. And if it is 16, then it means 16%.

Comment: It works fine. I am able to display the % sign next to the interest value. But the code is not reading the interest rate value when I click the select button. It is simply reading `""` and not printing anything in `TextBoxInterestRate`
This is how I am reading the interest rate value from the GridView: `TextBoxInterestRate.Text = GridViewSavingsTracker.Rows[rowID].Cells[3].Text;`

Comment: All the other fields from the GridView are reading the values fine.

Comment: I assume you are assigning the textbox value on RowDataBound in which case you should use `TextBoxInterestRate.Text = ((Literal) e.Row.FindControl("IntRate")).Text;`

Comment: `e.Row` is not being recognized. I am already reading the row ID in the following way: `int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);`

Comment: So you are setting the textbox value in `GridViewSavingsTracker_RowCommand` ? In such a case you can get the value of the Literal by doing `TextBoxInterestRate.Text = ((Label) row.FindControl("IntRate")).Text;` You will need to declare row first like such `var row = GridViewSavingsTracker.Rows[index]` and if you haven't got the index do so by `int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);`

Comment: what do you mean by `row`? Because `row.FindControl` is not being recognized

Comment: And you were right about assigning value to `TextBox` in `GridView_RowCommand()` method.

Comment: I have edited my answer to better illustrate the solution.

Comment: I am doing the following: `var row = GridViewSavingsTracker.Rows[rowID];` and then `TextBoxInterestRate.Text = ((Label)row.FindControl("interestRate")).Text;` But I am getting a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception. What is `Label`? `var row` is storing a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow` object.

Comment: What is `Label` in `TextBoxInterestRate.Text = ((Label)row.FindControl("interestRate")).Text;`?